# Angular2 Synchronous Http Call

Tags: angular, angular-http

When my Angular 2 app starts the first thing it must do is fetch a session id via a Server API call. All UI interactions require that session id, so I need to have fetched the id before continuing, i.e. I want to implement the Server API call synchronously. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: why don't you set your login page at first and then if you get data set the data or id in local storage which you can use all over the app if another case then share some code for better clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Use the login page as your default route and protect your routes using guards to make sure that nobody can access them without being logged in. Here is more information:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html